# Detect any function created with async def

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-asyncio, python-3.7, coroutine

I am puzzled by the following behavior in Python 3.6+:

```py
>>> def f1(): pass
>>> def f2(): yield
>>> async def f3(): pass
>>> async def f4(): yield
>>> inspect.isfunction(f1)
True
>>> inspect.isfunction(f2)
True
>>> inspect.iscoroutinefunction(f3)
True
>>> inspect.iscoroutinefunction(f4)
False
```

Both synchronous functions and generator functions are considered "functions" by inspect but asynchronous generator functions are not considered "coroutine functions".
This seems contrary to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.iscoroutinefunction)

> `inspect.iscoroutinefunction(object)`
>
> Return true if the object is a coroutine function (a function defined with an async def syntax).

Is there any better way to detect if a function was defined with `async`, including generator functions, than checking both `iscoroutinefunction` and `isasyncgenfunction`?

This may be due to the fact that asynchronous generators only appeared in 3.6 but is still puzzling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous generators are not themselves coroutines, and cannot be `await`ed:

```
>>> loop.run_until_complete(f4())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/haugh/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 447, in run_until_complete
    future = tasks.ensure_future(future, loop=self)
  File "/home/haugh/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 526, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
```

I think you have already identified the best way of checking if `async` was used to define the function:

```
def async_used(func):
    return inspect.iscoroutinefunction(func) or inspect.isasyncgenfunction(func)
```

Comment: Thank you, that explains why `iscoroutinefunction` returns `False` on `f4`. I would think though that its documentation should have been updated in 3.6 after the introduction of asynchronous generators...